# Dell PowerEdge R310 not starting - no power except for DRAC

Tags: dell-poweredge

I have a Dell PowerEdge R310 server which has been running for a few years. This morning it suddently powered off and I can't get it to power on again.

It has dual PSU and I have tried to reseat them and use only one, also reseated the CPU and RAM without any luck.

The front LCD panel is not showing any lights or info, the fans won't start and it seems to be totally dead except the PSU lights are on, the STB LED on the motherboard is on and the DRAC controller is working (but not reporting any details about the issue).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the motherboard power routing is seriously damaged. It happens, sometime. If your server is under support, call DELL for a motherboard replacement.

Comment: That was the case, Dell replaced the motherboard is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing both PS cables and press & hold the power button for a few seconds, then plug back the power chords and start the server.

Comment: Already tried that but no luck. Holding the power button 5-10 secs doesn't do anything.